# How to plot a dict of keys to lists where we are plotting the average of the list and showing ranges of the rest?[Python]

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have something along the lines of this dict:

`{10: [891, 506, 714, 430, 294, 659, 430, 430, 375, 430, 294, 714, 1510, 1049, 847, 430, 430, 430, 1410, 1657], 12: [676, 466, 719, 727, 573, 1202, 466, 719, 573, 885, 573, 573, 573, 573, 518, 518, 573, 573, 1465, 466]}`

I am trying to plot a graph where the x axis has the keys, (i.e: 10,12,14...) and the y axis represents the average of the list corresponding with the key and I want to show some bars which represent the quartiles or the possible range? Anyone have any idea how I can go about doing that?

This is in Python btw.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {10: [891, 506, 714, 430, 294, 659, 430, 430, 375, 430, 294, 714, 1510, 1049, 847, 430, 430, 430, 1410, 1657],
        12: [676, 466, 719, 727, 573, 1202, 466, 719, 573, 885, 573, 573, 573, 573, 518, 518, 573, 573, 1465, 466]}
keys = sorted(data)  # keys in a defined order

plt.boxplot([data[k] for k in keys], positions=keys)  # box-and-whisker plot
plt.plot(keys, [sum(data[k]) / len(data[k]) for k in keys], '-o')  # line for the mean

plt.savefig('nice-box-plots')
```

Adding `whis=(10, 90)` as argument to `plt.boxplot` will put the whiskers to the 10 and 90%tile, see the [doc of boxplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html).

[image: Screen-Shot-2020-05-06-at-22-51-13.png]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you turn your data into a `pandas` dataframe, carry on all calculation on that dataframe and plot. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
plot_data = df.agg(['mean', 'std']).T
plt.errorbar(plot_data.index, plot_data['mean'], yerr=plot_data['std'])
```

Output:

[image]